# Ajax Comment Form Not Returning ExpressionEngine Success Template Content

Tags: jquery, ajax, expressionengine, jquery-forms-plugin

So I have a basic comment form hooked up with the [jQuery Form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) (only members can post so no name/email fields):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets_site/js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      function ajaxReturn(data) {
        var messageContainer = $('.alert-box');
        var messageBody = $(data);
        messageContainer.html(messageBody);
      }// ajaxReturn(data)

      $('.member-review').ajaxForm({
        success: ajaxReturn
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
    {exp:channel:entries
      channel='products'
      limit='1'
      disable='categories|member_data|pagination'
    }
      {exp:comment:form
        channel='products'
        form_class='member-review'
        return='notifications/success'
      }
        <div class="alert-box">
          {!-- Ajax Form Errors --}
        </div><!--.alert-box-->

        <label for="comment">Tell others what you think</label>
        <textarea name="comment" rows="8" class="required" id="comment"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      {/exp:comment:form}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</body>
</html>
```

And, for the purposes of this demo, my success template could not be more simple:

```
<p>Sumission Successful!</p>
```

Unfortunately when I submit a completed form, no data is returned. If I add `console.log($(data));` to the ajaxReturn function, I get an empty string. The comment is successfully submitted to the database, it’s just the return template that doesn't seem to make it.

Really not sure why this is happening. It returns error messages correctly, just not the success template.

EE v2.5.3

**UPDATE:** [Here's a video](http://vimeo.com/12909760) that covers the basics of what I'm trying to do. I've successfully done it before on previous versions of EE, so I'm wondering if they changed something recently to make it not work anymore?

Comment: Have you checked the firebug/chrome network tab to see what HTTP response is being returned to your ajax call? Screenshot would be helpful. Also try just `console.log(data)` rather than wrapping it with `$()`.

Comment: @AdrianMacneil I'm not super great with the network tab, but if I submit the completed form with the network tab open, the "Response" tab is blank. `console.log(data)` returns nothing at all, while `console.log($(data))` returns an empty pair of brackets (`[]`). Conversely, if I submit a blank form and force an error, I get the full HTML of the EE notification template. What specifically would you like a screenshot of?

Comment: Actually now I think that's probably just how EE works when you post forms via AJAX. See my more detailed answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the jQuery form plugin, but it looks like it doesn't work like you expect (EE doesn't seem to return the content of the success page if you post the form via AJAX).

However, there's really no need for a whole separate template for such a simple success message. You could just do this in your return function:

```
function ajaxReturn(data) {
    $('.alert-box').html('<p>Sumission Successful!</p>');
}
```

Alternatively, if you absolutely must use a separate template (for consistency with non-JS browsers or whatever), you could just use the jQuery `load()` function to get its contents:

```
function ajaxReturn(data) {
    $('.alert-box').load('/notifications/success');
}
```

The second option would result in one more AJAX call to your server, but it's not really a big deal in the scheme of things. If you want the best performance, go with the first option.

**UPDATE:** If errors are also returned for your success function, what about this?

```
function ajaxReturn(data) {
    if (data) {
        $('.alert-box').html(data);
    } else {
        $('.alert-box').html('<p>Sumission Successful!</p>');
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is there's no way to handle error messages. The basic idea is the ajax loads whatever message is returned from the server. I've used the plugin before on previous EE contact forms and it worked fine. I'm wondering if they changed something in a recent version that's causing this conflict?

Comment: You've assigned the `ajaxReturn` function to the ajaxForm `success` variable - surely it won't run if the submission isn't successful?

Comment: It is my understanding that, as far as Ajax is concerned, "success" merely denotes whether or not the form submission was successfully sent to the server and a response was received. It has no way of knowing if the response it got back was an ExpressionEngine-specific error or success. That being said, I found an old forum post where [Rob Sanchez points out](http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/177523/#841917) that I can search for common html in the EE error message template, and conditionally perform actions based on if that code is present or not.

Comment: Well in this case it looks like EE returns nothing on success, and an error message on an error. See my update above - does that work?

Comment: Yes, the update you made seems to be the best solution. It's still annoying though because I'm certain it was possible to fetch the success template in earlier EE versions. Having to type out static success text in the JS is rather limiting :/

Comment: Strange that it's not possible now. You can always combine the two and use the jQuery load() function, or just put your success message in a hidden div and show it.

Comment: Just FWIW about jQuery load and something which I like allot is the fact that you can actually pull in specific html using an id for example: $('.alert-box').load('/notifications/success #container');

Comment: @AdrianMacneil @Natetronn I think I will use `.load()`, thanks for the tip! Still annoyed I have to make the extra ajax call :/ I'll have to submit a ticket to EllisLab about this issue.

Comment: @kgrote depending on how much you care about a few milliseconds, you could actually call load() at the same time you submit the form, so it's ready to go in case the submission was successful (make both ajax requests in parallel rather than sequentially).

Answer (score 1):

The docs https://github.com/malsup/form mention that ajaxForm only prepares the form for submission but does not submit it.
What happens when you run this?:

```
$('.member-review').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        target: '.alert-box'
    })
});
```

Comment: I tried your example code (you need a period before `alert-box`, btw) and got the exact same results. Errors came back fine, but a successful submission comes back totally blank.

Comment: damn, you have a url we can have a look at?

Comment: Sadly no, it's an NDA site. Can you duplicate the behavior on a 2.5.3 site? That would help me to know if it's an EE problem or a problem with my specific setup.

Answer (score 0):

Was it confirmed if this was a bug? I am having similar issue. I have a dev site that I was testing with newer EE version and the ajax post never returns a success message even though it does actually submit because if I refresh the page I can see the update. Where with the live site I am running an older version and I get the success and response. Was starting to go crazy thinking it was something with the server until I found this post.

I also am updating using the load of a template page but would be nice if I could use the json response so I do not have to make that extra call to the separate page. This is what I am using on the live (older EE version) and works properly.

```
    var update_cart_form_options = { 
        success: update_cart,  
        dataType: 'json' 
    };
    function update_cart(data, statusText, xhr, $form)  {   

        if (data.success) {                                                   
            $("input[name=XID]").val(data.XID);
            $('#cart_total')        .html( data.cart_total );
            $('#cart_subtotal')     .html( data.cart_subtotal );
        }  
        return false; 
    }      

    $("#update_button").click(function(){
        $('#update_button').val('Processing...');
        var form = $(this).closest("form"); 
        $(form).ajaxForm(update_cart_form_options);
        $(form).submit();  

});
```

But the same code will not work on the dev site testing with the latest EE version.

Comment: I don't think this was ever officially confirmed as a bug. When I brought it up on the support forums they moved it to "community support", I suspect because they thought it was a front-end Ajax problem, not an EE problem. I encourage you to [submit a bug report](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs), though.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Ellis for this so we will see what they say.